# ISDate in not working as expected in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, date

```
Declare @var varchar(100)
set @var  = '2000'

select 
    case when ISDATE(@var) = 1 
           then 'Valid Date' 
         when ISDATE(@var) = 0 
           then 'Invalid Date' 
    end
```

In the above code I have a value for `@var` of 2000, which is not a date. But if I check with the `isdate` function, it labels it as a valid date.

What could we do to get the expected output?

Thanks in advance

Comment: SQL Server disagrees with your interpretation - `select CONVERT(date,'2000')` runs without error. So, so far as SQL Server is concerned, `2000` is a date.

Answer (score 2):

i found interesting thing i hope this helps you

[ISDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx)`Returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value; otherwise, 0.`

ISDATE `returns 0 if the expression is a datetime2 value.`

if you run this

```
Declare @var varchar(100)
set @var  = '1753'

select cast(@var as datetime)

select 
    case when ISDATE(@var) = 1 
           then 'Valid Date' 
         when ISDATE(@var) = 0 
           then 'Invalid Date' 
    end
```

RESULT

[image]

if you run this

```
Declare @var varchar(100)
set @var  = '1752'

select cast(@var as datetime)
```

> ERROR: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

because [DATETIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187819.aspx) Date range `January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999` in your case when you run a query which is actually `ISDATE('2000-01-01 00:00:00.000')` which is valid ISDATE assumes it is DATETIME.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an additional guard clause to your case statement requiring @var to be longer than 7 chars ('2000-1-1')

```
select case when LEN(@VAR) > 7 and ISDATE(@var)=1 then 'Valid Date' 
            when LEN(@var) < 8 or  ISDATE(@var)=0 then 'Invalid Date' END
```